# Ошибка при сохранении файла документа в 1С

Tags: 1с

1С 8.3 Управляемые формы

При сохранении файла в формате ".txt", ".doc" и т.д. происходит ошибка:

> Ошибка при выполнении файловой операции'/e1cib/data/. Значение данного
>   типа невозможно преобразовать для передачи как файл. (Неопределено)

Доработку делал по статье http://infostart.ru/public/408860/

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться и исправить.

Answer (score 2):

Для наиболее точного ответа на вопрос необходимо указывать полную версию платформы 1С:Предприятие и, желательно, указать программный код в котором возникли проблемы.

Ваша задача обычно решается таким кодом:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ВыбратьФайл(Команда)

    НачатьПодключениеРасширенияРаботыСФайлами(Новый ОписаниеОповещения(
        "ОповещениеПодключенияРасширенияРаботыСФайлами", ЭтотОбъект));

КонецПроцедуры // ВыбратьФайл()

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОповещениеПодключенияРасширенияРаботыСФайлами(Подключено, 
    ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт

    Если Подключено Тогда

        Диалог = Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие);
        Диалог.Заголовок = НСтр("ru='Выберите файл загрузки в формате (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xml, *.csv, *.txt)'");
        Диалог.ПолноеИмяФайла = "";
        Диалог.МножественныйВыбор = Ложь;
        Диалог.ПредварительныйПросмотр = Истина;
        Диалог.Фильтр = "Формат (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xml;*.csv;*.txt)|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xml;*.csv;*.txt|"; 
        Диалог.Показать(Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ОповещениеВыборФайла", ЭтотОбъект));

    Иначе

        // Сообщить что не удалось подключить расширение

    КонецЕсли;

КонецПроцедуры // ОповещениеПодключенияРасширенияРаботыСФайлами()

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОповещениеВыборФайла(ВыбранныеФайлы, ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт

    Если ВыбранныеФайлы = Неопределено Тогда
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;    

    Если ВыбранныеФайлы.Количество() = 1 Тогда

        НачатьПомещениеФайла(Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ОповещениеВыборФайлаНаСервере", ЭтотОбъект), 
            , // Можно указать строковой реквизит тогда адрес будет так же в этом реквизите 
            ВыбранныеФайлы[0], 
            Ложь, 
            УникальныйИдентификатор);

    Иначе
        // Сообщить что можно выбрать только один файл
    КонецЕсли;

КонецПроцедуры // ОповещениеВыборФайла() 

&НаСервере
Процедура ОповещениеВыборФайлаНаСервере(Результат, Адрес, ВыбранноеИмяФайла, 
    ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт

    ПутьКФайлу = ПолучитьИмяВременногоФайла();
    ДвоичныеДанные = ПолучитьИзВременногоХранилища(Адрес);
    ДвоичныеДанные.Записать(ПутьКФайлу); 

    ТекстовыйДокумент = Новый ТекстовыйДокумент();
    ТекстовыйДокумент.Прочитать(ПутьКФайлу);
    Содержимое = ТекстовыйДокумент.ПолучитьТекст();

    УдалитьФайлы(ПутьКФайлу);

КонецПроцедуры // ОповещениеВыборФайлаНаСервере()
```

P.S. Прикрепил [ссылку](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnn07eflgkkwso2/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0.epf?dl=0) на пример обработки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш вариант решение очень пригодился!